# wordpress $wpdb->getresults with SELECT .. WHERE .. IN

Tags: select, wordpress

I have been trying to use `SELECT` .. `WHERE` .. `IN`

```
global $wpdb;         
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_search WHERE name IN ('s','w','a')";  

$result = $wpdb->get_results ( $sql );
if ( $result )
{
   print_r($result);
}
```

but it fails and returns an error. Is there any alternative for this Select statement or anything else I need to do to make this function as expected?

Comment: do you have a table named 'wp_search'?

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is absolutely working fine for me** nevertheless you can refer this alternative

```
global $wpdb;

$special_entries = array( 'inherit', 'auto-draft', 'unanswered' );
$how_many = count($special_entries);
$placeholders = array_fill(0, $how_many, '%s');

$format = implode(', ', $placeholders);

$query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status IN($format)";

$results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare($query, $special_entries) );
```

Comment: @inblues please accept this answer if it is helped you.